# Count the number of sequences (identical values) in a column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable with different occurrences of 0 and 1 and would like to have a counter for the sequences in this variable. Each time a value changes, the counter should be increased. How can I create the sequence vector with `dplyr` commands:

```
data <- data.frame(variable = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1))
data$sequence <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also is there any reason it has to be a `dplyr` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of diff and cumsum:

```
data %>% mutate(seq=cumsum(c(1,diff(sequence)!=0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, sequence := rleid(variable)]
data
#    variable sequence
# 1:        0        1
# 2:        0        1
# 3:        1        2
# 4:        1        2
# 5:        1        2
# 6:        0        3
# 7:        1        4
# 8:        0        5
# 9:        0        5
#10:        1        6
#11:        1        6
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a base R solution using `rle`

```
data$sequence <- rep(seq(z<-rle(data$variable)$lengths),z)
```

such that

```
> data
   variable sequence
1         0        1
2         0        1
3         1        2
4         1        2
5         1        2
6         0        3
7         1        4
8         0        5
9         0        5
10        1        6
11        1        6
```